# Running python script with external libraries in apache nifi docker image

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I want to start an Apache/nifi(docker image) container with a template I have.
The template contains an ExecuteScript processor which runs a python script.
This works fine on NiFi running locally, but not on its docker image. Is there any solution to this.

Comment: pls share what steps you followed and errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

If the [`ExecuteScript`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) processor retains the script in the *Script Body* processor property, it will be stored inline during template serialization. If instead, it references a file on disk via the *Script File* property, that file must be present in the specified location on the Docker instance, so you will need to perform a `COPY` operation in your *Dockerfile*.